# How to use logic classes with styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I want to use this logic to applying the corresponding class to an element:

```
<ul onClick={handleClick} className={click ? 'dropdown-menu clicked' : 'dropdown-menu'}>
```

But I am using styled components, I don't understand how I can use logic to totally change the component. Any ideas? I am using Next.js

Answer (score 1):

> You can pass a function ("interpolations") to a styled component's template literal to adapt it based on its props.

Read this section, [Adapting based on props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props), in Styled Component documentation. In your case, because you didn't provide the details of the code, I can only give you an example:

```
const DropdownMenu = styled.div`
  display: ${props => props.clicked ? "none" : "block"};
`;
```